# Poisson equation on a Torus

Tags: riemann-surfaces, compact-manifolds

I need an example for a Poisson equation ($\triangle_S u = F $) on a torus. Specifically, i will appreciate a function F and its corresponding analytic solution ($u_{ex}$). Any reference will be ok.

Comment: i found an example in this [book](http://books.google.at/books/about/Numerical_Methods_for_Two_phase_Incompre.html?id=YVIM2CviC5QC&redir_esc=y)